# JQuery Modal on close, refresh the calling page

Tags: jquery

I have a simple HTML form that displays a list or records.
I also have a NEW button that looks like this:

```
 <button id="newBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">New</button>
```

The forms displays well and it has a Jquery event to add the new record on the database.
The end of the jquery call looks like this: 
     `$('#myModal').modal('toggle');` which hides the modal form.

**Question:**
What's the right way to, after I close/hide the Modal form, to automatically refresh the html list so that the new record appears on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just add this to the end of the function:

```
location.reload();
```

Or this (this get's called after the modal has been hidden) :

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    location.reload();
});
```